# How to preprocess data for Word2Vec?

Tags: nlp, data, preprocessing, word-embeddings, word2vec

I have text data which is crawled from websites. I am preprocessing data to train Word2Vec model. Should I remove stopwords and do lemmatization? How to preprocess data for Word2Vec?

Comment: Different libraries require different preprocessing steps. What are you working with?

Comment: I am using gensim but open to try different libraries too. @Leevo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the community,

I do not know about other libraries, but gensim has a very good API to create word2vec models. In order to preprocess data, you have to decide first what things you are gonna keep in your vocab and whatnot. for ex:- Punctuations, numbers, alphanumeric words(ex - 42nd) etc.

In my knowledge, the most generic preprocessing pipeline is the following:-

1) Convert to lower
2) Remove punctuations/symbols/numbers (but it is your choice)
3) Normalize the words (lemmatize and stem the words)

Once this is done, now you can tokenize the sentence into uni/bi/tri-grams.

Have a look at [this](https://medium.com/@datamonsters/text-preprocessing-in-python-steps-tools-and-examples-bf025f872908)

The generic format to put data in gensim.models.word2vec()'s sentence parameter is : [[tokeneized sentence 1], [tokenized sentence 2].....and so on]

Hope it helps, thanks!!

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: great if this question solves your problem, kindly accept this answer as solution so that the admin can take it off from the open questions domain. Thanks!!

Comment: I tried 2 versions of it, one with normalized words another without normalizing. In my case, without normalization model works better. Thanks!

Comment: nice, please have look at this to accept this solution as asnwer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer